# GADInterstitial AdMob showing default ad every time

Tags: ios, swift, admob, interstitial

In my app I am using a `GADInterstitial` and its showing the ad perfectly but its showing the same default ad of AdMob every time. 
Here is my code:

```
self.interstitialAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx")
let request = GADRequest()
self.interstitialAd.loadRequest(request)
self.interstitialAd = reloadInterstitialAd()

func reloadInterstitialAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}
```

And the resulting ad:

[image]

Comment: What is this *default ad* you're referencing? Add a screenshot of it to your question. Also, add the `reloadInterstitialAd()` function to your question.

Comment: please check my question i update it @DanielStorm

Comment: Still there is no screenshot of default ad.

Comment: please check my question i upload the default image@DanielStorm , @Umair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default ad* you're referring to is the test ad AdMob delivers when you're presenting ads on a test device. If your Ad Unit ID is correct, real paid ads will appear in the release version of your application.

Also, your code is redundant. The first 3 lines aren't necessary as you're doing the same thing in your `reloadInterstitialAd()` function. Remove them. For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.interstitialAd = loadInterstitialAd()
}

func loadInterstitialAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}
```

I've also renamed the function to `loadInterstitialAd()` to make it clearer.